# How to convert PDF to bitmap with google docs viewer or other application, in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have an url with pdf file and i need it to convert to jpegs or pngs. Can any body help me with this? I use php for my site and i need this feature.

Comment: Is the URL on your site, or an external site? Do you want to do the conversion programmatically, with PHP? Should this really be tagged as 'google docs'?

Comment: No i don't need to programmatically convert. I need a service to do this regulary. For example i can work with google docs viewer. I need to post and url(on my host) with pdf, and get a couple of urls to download a pictures that was created from my pdf. I have pdf with 5 pages, i need 5 pictures.

Comment: Hi there. It's still not clear, but perhaps if the essence of your question is "convert PDF to JPG" then the answer from @Baba should assist you. If so, then that is programmatic conversion - if it is not, then this probably isn't the right site for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `imagemagick` http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.

Example

```
$url = "" ; //URl to document ;
$tmp = tmpfile() . ".pdf";
file_put_contents($tmp, file_get_contents($url));
exec("convert -density 300 $tmp image.jpg");
```